# How to write the cuda kernel for convolutions?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpgpu, convolution

I am totally new in cuda and I would like to write a cuda kernel that calculates a convolution given an input matrix, convolution (or filter) and an output matrix.

Note: I want each thread of the cuda kernel to calculate one value in the output matrix.

How can I do this?

Comment: As far as I remember there were dozens of examples on the CUDA website. Especially given the fact that convolution is a very common task. Has this changed or haven't you found anything there?

Comment: @CWBudde thank you for your comment. Yes i found couple of long example with many hard cases all over the websites, but  I haven't find straightforward one yet unfortunately. I will be more than happy if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

If the filters cover fill range of the matrix, then it can be directly converted to *cublasSgemm*.

For example, suppose the dimensions of the matrix is 5 * 4, and you need 130 filters, then the filters matrix to be trained is of dimensions 130 * 20, and the 5 * 4 matrix can be taken as 20 * 1.

In this way, the computation speed is optimal; it's converted to matrix multiplication between m1 (130, 20) and m2 (20, 1).

Comment: thanks for your comment and example. it gave me some understanding about the problem. Do you also have some cuda code example to do this. i would like to know how it works by real example if its possible. Thanks

Comment: I always call Cuda library with "JCuda" so the codes are not in C. You can check cublasSgemm examples on the Web as well as the examples on Cuda manual. Do sgemm with operations 'N' and 'N' and set lda and ldb and ldc as 130, 20, and 130. It takes a little time to get familiar with using the cublasSgemm method.

Comment: thanks. sure i will check and code and i will update you.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to write a cuda kernel that calculates a convolution given an input matrix, convolution (or filter) and an output matrix.

You might be interested in [this treatment](https://www.evl.uic.edu/sjames/cs525/final.html) of the subject (although it's a little old). Or look at the CUDA convolution kernel sample programs: [non-separable](https://github.com/zchee/cuda-sample/tree/master/3_Imaging/convolutionTexture) and [separable](https://github.com/zchee/cuda-sample/tree/master/3_Imaging/convolutionSeparable)

> I want each thread of the cuda kernel to calculate one value in the output matrix.

If you follow the link, you'll realize you don't quite want that. In other words: Don't make rigid assumptions regarding how your kernel should divide work among the threads, you might change your mind later.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a image convolution kernel, this link may be helpful ([Two Dimensional (2D) Image Convolution in CUDA by Shared & Constant Memory: An Optimized way](http://www.cstechera.com/2015/07/two-dimensional-2d-image-convolution-in-CUDA.html) ).

As far as I concerned, using each thread to calculate a pixel or position in output may not be a very good idea. Please consider how the sub-region for this convolution is loaded, or whether the threads in the same warp are reading continuous memory at each read. Otherwise, the kernel may suffer from the data loading even though over hundreds of threads are available.

Therefore, basically you can just write the code your described, and using the profiler (nvvp) for further optimization suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for comment and referenced website. I am only looking for creating a 2 dimensional convolution kernel for use on GPUs using CUDA. At the end, i would like my code to print the input, filter and output matrices.

Comment: Does code in your link perform winograd (or any other subcubic) conv?